# How should I push back against my job assigning "homework"?

Tags: work-environment, negotiation

I was placed on a personal improvement program a few weeks ago for making too much conversation at work. I had to move my desk to my manager's office and we started a much more intensive training program to get me up to speed, since for 8 months no one would assign me any work except for easy scripts or stupid impossible tasks like "Make a program that lets me speak to Microsoft Word". The job is bioinformatics by the way, and yes I'm actively applying for new jobs.

The project manager who's doing this training is assigning me homework, and I've already said that I'll only do it if I have time at work. I didn't for this last assignment, and he got mad and said this looks bad for me on a PIP, and I should be doing it at home to prove that I "want to stay here".

I'm paid hourly, not a salary, so this really would be working for free. What's a good way to push back against this?

Comment: What sort of tasks?   Can you elaborate?    Is he asking you to do major projects in your off time?  Or something as simple as reading a short article?

Comment: If you're paid hourly, your location makes a difference.  Are you in the US?

Comment: "Work for free" what do you call the pay they already gave you whilst you were on "Workplace"? If anything, it sounds like you are ahead on pay, and will be for the foreseeable future.

Comment: Probably you were not **placed on a personal improvement program a few weeks ago for posting on The Workplace too much during work hours** but were placed because you have achieved way less that you were expected during your actual work.

Comment: How many hours did you spend on The Workplace?
Compare it to how many hours it takes to do the homework.
Suck it up, do the job and in a meanwhile look for a new job if you don't feel good where you are, but don't expect any other place will accept worker wasting paid hours for some internet shenanigans.

Comment: There are inconsistencies in this question which are quite crucial to the advice to be given. Do you count The Workplace hours towards your worked hours that you charge for? If so, the homework is kinda understandable. Also a program to "bring up to speed" and not having an assignment are different things. You can be brought up to speed when you are slow doing normal tasks, not training. If you have essential skills to do the job, then why not give you one and let you be slow at first? It seems that you were paid for 8 months and still not produced value. This might change perspective.

Comment: Piling on the STFUGBTW bandwagon is fun. But I just want to note that this person only has two posts on Workplace.

Comment: @WilliamEntriken Presumably this is a different account than their normal one. Member for 20 days (as of this comment) which is within the "a few weeks ago" stated in the OP.

Comment: Consider recording the hours taken to do the homework. When PIP ends or they fire you file for wage theft for unpaid overtime.

Comment: Are you actually actively trying to get sacked?

Comment: I'm just wondering what kind of job it is you're doing.  If it's programming, which I remember this being about before the question got edited- then you should have been proactive about learning the language to include reading books and acquiring certification during your off time (even if your employer didn't offer to pay for any of it).  You shouldn't have to be told to learn...

Comment: @Zorkolot There is a major difference between learning new things and being assigned tasks from job to do at home. You don't learn for the company - you learn for yourself and your own career. OP - you should choose how you want to continue your career. If you want to continue working there and using the technology you are learning - one way would be telling your manager that instead of assigned homework, you would rather learn more about things you didn't fully understand at the PIP at work, or learn different parts of what's needed and that you are fine with being evaluated from that later.

Comment: I'd love to know the backstory on why this user account no longer exists. But I expect that, as with many things, I'll have to accept that my (let's face it, prurient) curiousity will never be satisfied...

Comment: Putting in for OT or not completing the assignments are a sure thing for negative marks on the PIP under the grounds of "Unable to complete workload within regular working hours".  Lots of PIPs are unbeatable even without negative marks.  I would take your outside of work time that they want spent on homework and increase your job hunting time by that much.

Comment: @Rachey this is before the rather massive edits and OP admitting he was goofing off during office hours by talking excessively with coworkers.  OP never answered any clarification answers to begin with in this thread, so whether it was pure "homework" (and we understand that homework in the educational sense implies studying) or office work is debatable.  But he's probably not being assigned "more work" if he's already doing shitty work as he himself described his own work.  Why would his employer want more of his shitty work after hours?

Comment: [def worth taking a look at the original post](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/revisions/137423/1).  That edit was more than just "Fixed spelling!"

Comment: @SandyGifford Really! Maybe it should be rolled back or re-edited?

Comment: Rolled back, that is a substantial change of facts in a way that doesn't read as an accident.

Comment: "Make a program that lets me speak to Microsoft Word" is not an impossible task. There are speech recognition libraries available now, including FOSS ones, and MS Word has a COM interface to run commands in it from external programs. If you couldn't research that, you are probably unfit for the job.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is: If, as you say, you are paid hourly, then you could say that you expect to be paid for any extra time that you have to put in and that you will record this time on your timesheet. (Or however hours are kept.) You could soften it by saying, "hey, I just can't keep up with this workload", i.e. make it your problem instead of a complaint about the company.

That said, how much "homework" are you being asked to do? If it's 8 hours a day, then yeah, I'd push back. If it's a few hours a week, I'd just do it.

You say that you're being given this work because you were reprimanded for an earlier infraction. I don't know if that complaint about your work was justified or not, or reasonable or not. But in general I'd advise you to suck it up and do what you're asked. Unless it is really over the top unreasonable. Even then, I'd say if at all possible, do it while you are looking for another job.

I've had jobs where I didn't like something the company asked me to do for one reason or another. My response has always been to do what I was asked while looking for another job. That way you can leave on good terms. You never know what will happen in the future. Maybe some day you'll want to come back to this company. Maybe someday you'll get another job and your old boss from this company will be there. I've had several times that I found myself working with people that I had known from a previous job.

Sure, I've seen those scenes in movies where someone curses the boss out and storms out in righteous indignation. I don't doubt that it feels good. But aside from the emotional surge, it does you zero good, and may do you active harm. That might be appropriate if the company demanded you do something illegal or that violates your morals, but not for a routine complaint.

Comment: Thanks, this is a much more reasonable answer than Joe posted.

Comment: How can the OP leave on good terms with a company that's pip-ing them? Why would the OP want to pretend to be incompetent when they are in the process of being fired for exactly that? When exactly is the OP going to cash in these 'brownie' points from doing unpaid overtime,  given that the company is in the process of firing them?

Comment: @NathanCooper I'm sorry, was I unclear on that point? He may want to come back to this company someday in the future. Even if not, if his experience there is so unpleasant that he would never want to come back, he might run into some of the same people at another job in the future. That is, he might "cash in the brownie points" at a future job. Even if you suppose that that is unlikely, it's certainly possible. As I said, it's happened to me. Can you imagine any scenario where screaming at the boss and storming out in a rage would help you in any way ... besides the emotional satisfaction?

Comment: There is a difference between rage quitting and not being a doormat who does free work.

Comment: @bruglesco At the same time, OP hasn't done any work in 8 months. I'd say the company has put in a fair investment into taking care of the OP, who seems to be unwilling to repay.

Comment: Just imagine what the company's referral will sound like if contacted by a prospective employer after quitting...

Comment: @bruglesco I'd say that depends how much free work. An extra 60 hours a week on top of his regular 40 for no additional pay? I doubt I'd be willing to do that. An extra 2 hours a week? I would. It's pretty speculative, you may or may not ever get anything for it. But you'd be giving up, what?, a few hours of watching TV or playing video games probably.

Comment: I'm not saying there isn't nuance here. I for one would like clarification from OP soon exactly what the homework is. It clearly makes a huge difference. I was just attacking your standards that there only way to not have to free work is to rage quit. You can push back professionally. Would I? Depends on the details that the OP left out.

Comment: @bruglesco Well, I wouldn't say that's the ONLY alternative. I was trying to contrast two extremes: doing what you're asked, possibly while looking for another job, with refusing to do what you're asked and quitting on bad terms or being fired. Sure, "screaming obscenities and storming out in a rage" is the extreme. But saying "no, I'm not going to do the work assigned to me" is just not something that it is going to be taken well no matter how mild your tone of voice when you say it.

Comment: **My response has always been to do what I was asked while looking for another job** - I agree completely and would recommend this to anyone and everyone. Personally I add an additional step, which is to *gently* make sure my feelings on the task(s) are known. A few years ago I told a high up person in the company I worked for, "I don't *want* to do that but I'm *willing* to do that if I have no other choice." He said I had no other choice, so I started doing the thing at work and polished up and sent out my resume that very evening after work. And got a better job.

Comment: I have a very simple rule - I don't do work unless I'm being paid.

Comment: @AaronMcMillin ... said the man who just got fired from his third job in a row. Well, sure, if someone demands I work for him for nothing, I'm not going to do that -- unless he's pointing a gun at my head or something. But the question here isn't working for nothing. The OP says he's been paid for 8 months to do nothing, and now the boss is demanding he put in some extra hours at no extra so he can become productive. It's not working for nothing, it's working more hours for the same pay, in order to keep those paychecks coming.

Comment: If they paid OP for 8 months to do nothing, it's their own failure in management. OP is paid hourly, if he's not on the clock he should not be doing work, full stop. In a number of jurisdictions it's illegal to ask OP to do so.

Comment: @AaronMcMillin Depends what this "homework" is. If it's regular work, yes, could be illegal. But if it's, "We'd like you to study to learn new skills" or "we'd like you to complete this worksheet on good work habits" ... I don't think those rules would apply. I'm not a lawyer. Might depend on subtleties, like whether it's phrased as a requirement for your job or as something you would be wise to do to get ahead, etc.

Comment: @AaronMcMillin "paid for 8 months to do nothing ... failure in management". Or it could be that the company is trying to be understanding and compassionate. I suppose that "hey, let's give the kid another chance" could be a management failure from a very hard-nosed perspective. Personally I'd call it being a decent human being.

Answer (score 87):

> I had to move my desk to my manager's office and we started a much
>   more intensive training program to get me up to speed, since for 8
>   months no one would assign me any work except for easy scripts or
>   stupid impossible tasks like "Make a program that lets me speak to
>   Microsoft Word". The job is bioinformatics by the way, and yes I'm
>   actively applying for new jobs.
>
> The project manager who's doing this training is assigning me
>   homework, and I've already said that I'll only do it if I have time at
>   work. I didn't for this last assignment, and he got mad and said this
>   looks bad for me on a PIP, and I should be doing it at home to prove
>   that I "want to stay here".
>
> I'm paid hourly, not a salary, so this really would be working for
>   free. What's a good way to push back against this?

Since you don't want to stay there and you have already decided you don't want to do the work for free, simply say that you won't do unpaid work from home. Then don't do it.

Clearly you are on a path to be gone soon anyway, and this will make them angry again. Being on a Performance Improvement Plan pretty much always assures that you will either quit or be fired at the end no matter what you do but it doesn't appear that you care. So no use doing any free work.

You could offer to stay and work extra hours in the office (i.e., not for free) if you so choose.

Comment: What warrants the comments *clearly you're on a path to be gone soon anyway* and *it doesn't appear that you care* ? Plus this "free work" sounds like it is *training,* so it's likely that the company isn't even directly benefiting from it.

Comment: (Sorry, I understand the first comment, but I'm not sure OP does, so I think it needs more explanation)

Comment: Didn't see the edit. It certainly changes things a lot! Kinda skeptical of the PIP = fired regardless part, but not my area of expertise!

Comment: @Mars: Joe is right. Being put on a PIP does mean the employee is going to be fired no matter what he/she does. Giving "homework" is just an excuse (they'll find something wrong with the homework even if he/she does it well) to bring up accusations that will lead to being fired. OP has to actively look for a new job instead of wasting time doing the homework.

Comment: @Joe Strazzere - "Additionally, a Performance Improvement Plan pretty much always assures that you will be fired at the end no matter what you do." - In this case, I agree, the company sees no value in the OP. But, a PIP can also be used to change the behavior of an otherwise valuable employee.

Comment: I tend to agree with what you wrote about PIP and the local equivalent in Israel (שימוע לפני פיטורין) but I couldn't find any data on either - I would really love some numbers like "this percent of people who went on a PIP ended up being fired". I have a guess that this number is 99% but some data would be awesome. If anyone can finds some (general) data and edit it in that would be swell to back this answer up.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum The problem with a study like that is selection bias, there are a lot of bad workers out there.  Plus a significant number of people are going to look for another job instead of trying to improve since they expect to be fired.

Comment: I actually saw someone survive a PIP, but its the first time I've ever heard of that.

Comment: *"Being on a Performance Improvement Plan pretty much always assures that you will be fired at the end no matter what you do"* - Is this actually the case? You would think that at least some companies would use a performance improvement plan in good faith (ie actually to improve an employees performance)

Comment: I've worked at at least a few places that used PIPs in good faith to send a clear message about specific problem behaviors. I think it's valid to see a PIP as the a permanent source of drag on professional advancement, and it's probably a good move to look for other work, but my personal experience suggests that it's not always a direct prelude to a pink slip.

Comment: PIPs are just to prove to HR that management tried to help you and are often required in order to terminate someone for performance-related reasons. Good managers will attempt to correct undesired behavior without one. As a result, if such a manager is going through the effort of creating and filing a PIP, it means all other attempts at correction have failed and you are probably beyond redemption in their eyes. In this case, the PIP is just a formality so they can terminate you.

Comment: I've survived a PIP (it was for a minor issue in an area where I had uncommon expertise, but still). I'll agree that a PIP isn't a great sign, but it's fundamentally going to be associated with work performance below what the employer wants-- and those employees, consequently, are going to be disproportionately fired/reassigned/demoted relative to others. To say that it's definitely an early (and irrevocable) step in a firing process is strictly inaccurate. It's fair to say that the job of a person on a PIP is in jeopardy, but more than that is too reductive and not well supported.

Comment: Unfair, but some companies force the managers to grade their people on a curve. The lowest rated are then invariably put on a PIP. I have seen many people survive PIPs, some even flourish afterward.

Comment: I agree that a PIP is not an automatic death sentence by any means.  But a PIP for lack of productivity that results in more whining about too much work is, in this case, not likely to lead anywhere else

Comment: For PIPs to actually serve their intended purpose (to document issues with employees for purposes of making termination easier) they must sometimes be successful. Courts are not always completely gullible.

Comment: The lead engineer on my team was on PIP many years ago. I highly disagree that you're pretty much going to end up getting fired if you're on one- unless you continue to perform badly/refuse to correct the behavior that landed you on one in the first place

Comment: @JMK of course. it makes no sense from a practical sense. It's just a way for HR to be like "well we tried" and to put themselves on some high horse, to imply that they care about workers.

Comment: I was fired after being on a PIP. The feedback I received was "You complied with everything we asked you to do and clearly improved, but we're going to fire you anyway." So, yes, in my experience a PIP is just the company's (or HR's) way of covering themselves. They actively encouraged me to quit the job almost every day.

Answer (score 24):

If you're interested in remaining employed there, and the number of hours of this "homework" isn't excessive, then maybe you should consider doing it, seeing as you've spent some number of hours for which you were paid doing personal things like posting on Workplace.

That seems like a fair and equitable way of dealing with this.

They pay you to work. You've been paid for time that you were at work but were doing personal things. If you want them to respect your time and money then you must respect theirs. If you want to get paid for the time that you work then you must work for the time that you get paid for.

It's a two way street.

Comment: *It's a two way street* This. I'd give it it's own line to make it stand out more

Comment: If we take the OP case at face value -- clocking in to work 8 months and not assigned any tasks -- then how much unpaid work do think they now owe the company?

Comment: @DanielR.Collins They are paid for being available to do work they are assigned. If no one assigns them any tasks, management has failed. Especially in the first months you have to supervise new colleagues (= at least one weekly progress meeting) until you are confident that they can work on their own.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins they don't own the company anything. It's the company's fault that OP was not assigned tasks, not OP's.

Comment: @Ave: I agree, but this particular answer hinges on the OP seeming to owe the workplace time for past pay, so I'm looking for clarification or limit of that claim.

Answer (score 16):

Define *homework*.

If you're being asked to do workplace tasks in your own time, that clearly isn't acceptable. If the homework is directly linked to a project, consider complaining.

However, you say you're on a PIP. This implies that you are lacking key skills to do your job - and not just that, but that you were probably lacking those skills when you started. An employer can use a PIP to give you the chance to acquire and practice those skills, but it would be a stretch to assume that they had to let you do it all on work time. If the homework is more like working through maths exercises, then absolutely you can be expected to do that kind of studying in your own time.

Of course you can choose not to. But if you're on a PIP, you're being given a last chance to prove you want to stay at the company and do that job. At any point, if it doesn't look like you're taking that opportunity, they can fire you. So that's your call really.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of spending work-time on stack exchange, do you work.

Then do stack exchange at home.

This eliminates the need for homework and will serve you well should you stay at this job or go to another.  If you do the work well, it will effectively make the PIP successful, and you will be too.

Answer (score 4):

Get an email from your manager instructing you that it should be done at home, outside regular hours.

Do it, put in the hours for it on your time-sheet, like you would for any other work. If they don't pay you, file an unpaid wage claim with your state DoL (or federal DoL if you're in Florida).

If they terminate you after the unpaid wage claim, file a wrongful termination complaint with the DoL.

They then have a fun time of proving it wasn't retaliation regarding your unpaid wage claim, especially once the PIP and 'homework' comes up during the investigation, which you will make sure it does.

After the unpaid wage claim, they will know that any termination will result in the DoL coming a-knockin', and don't want that headache, so they likely won't fire you. Employers are exceedingly labor lawsuit averse, oddly enough.

If they do fire you, you're not really any worse off as now you likely have unemployment (which they likely won't fight due to the unpaid wage claim) and your unpaid wage payout to buoy you while you job search.

Your state DoL website is a good resource to reference regarding your legal protections RE: unpaid wages, claims, and retaliation.

EDIT: I want to add - this isn't bulletproof. Legal processes take a while, you could lose your claims, it's all down to 'what will the other people involved in this process decide.', but I offer it as an alternative to 'grin and bear it', and I personally think it's a reasonable course.

Comment: You're teaching a leech how to exploit the legal system to screw over a decent business for giving the leech free money for 8 months? This is why businesses shouldn't be good samaritans. This leech should've been fired long ago.  Downvoted.

Comment: @Jack It's odd that you would advocate someone NOT exercising their legal rights.By all means, feel free to drive everyone's wages down by doing unpaid labor, but please don't encourage others to do so as well, or downvote information about how to avoid being illegally forced to do so.

Comment: Whether someone is or is not at fault for their poor work performance isn't an excuse to allow them to be forced into performing unpaid work illegally. There is a reason that wage theft is the largest form of theft in America by far, and a large amount of it is people doing unpaid work and not knowing they have options to enforce their right to fair pay for their time.

Comment: Ok, now I know for sure you're trolling.

Comment: If I was trolling I'd just call you mean 4 letter words. Clearly I am trying to persuade other people reading these comments that your outlook is bad.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the big picture, here. It may not be your fault, but it sounds like you do not match their expectations of you. If that's true, then the only thing worse than staying would be to get another job which has the similar expectations.

> "Since for 8 months no one would assign me any work..."

For whatever reason, you have not been able to meet the company's needs for 8 months. Perhaps your hiring manager misunderstood your level of experience. Perhaps you misunderstood their expectations. Interviewing is hard, and we all get it wrong.

It sounds like they were hoping you would show more initiative, since they did not prepare someone to train you 8 months ago. In fact, it may be that all of the people who are qualified to train you are already stretched thin within their own roles.

> "... except for easy scripts or stupid impossible tasks like "Make a program that lets me speak to Microsoft Word".

The folks assigning work to you may not be qualified to do your job. They may not even be qualified to know exactly what your job is, or what the difference is between a small script and voice recognition software.

If that is the case, they were hoping that you were fully equipped to carry out that role on your own, without support from a more senior developer; or perhaps that you would seek and find your own mentorship within the company. In other words, these people view your professional development as your problem to solve; they need you to be ready to meet their needs right away.

> "... we started a much more intensive training program to get me up to speed..."

So now, you have been assigned a PM, who is likely working extra hours to get his/her primary job done. That person is covering for your mistakes. He does not care if it was your fault or not. He does not care if you must do homework, because your job is now *his* homework. His success in his role is now tied (at least partially) to you. His priority is to make sure he does nothing wrong so that he will not be blamed if you fail.

This PM could look bad by giving you leniency, because (ostensibly) the PM's job is to get you ready to meet the company's expectations. In reality, I've heard that a PIP is often a formality, to make sure they do not get sued when they fire you.

Be careful how much you push back. Charging the company for the hours you spend outside of work sounds reasonable to me. However, know that if you push back too much, you are already very close to being fired. That will give you more time to focus on your job search. Do you have enough in savings to survive for a few weeks or months?

---

I would look for a job which has more opportunity to train you. A recruiter can help you find a good fit. My first employer did not emphasize experience, and would take anyone who said they were willing to learn to program. My boss was also a software developer (the position I was hired for), and he would feed me any task in three or four pieces if I could not grasp the big picture myself. Also, because he was a developer, he knew exactly how much I should be able to accomplish in my first week, and did not overwhelm me. He spent time finding the perfect tasks for me to get started on, so I could train by developing code to go into the product.

That was a lot of extra work for my boss! He was willing to do all that because he could not afford to reward someone for experience. He had a limited budget, and the company had a policy of hiring on one-year contracts: no full-time employees. Before hiring me, he had just lost or let go everyone in my role, and I was the first of three replacements he had hired. I had no future there, but it was a great place to start out.

My second job required me to display a lot more initiative. I was not ready for it, and nearly got fired in the first year. Someone else covered my mistakes, and I adapted. This experience is part of your adaptation. I'm sorry that the job is not working out, but it will be an important step to build your future. Hang in there!